# How do I search the content of 7-Zip archives (.7z)?

Tags: windows, search, archiving, 7-zip

I am looking for a way to search the content of files inside of a [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) archive (.7z) without having to unpack the archive. I have many 7-Zip archives with code inside them and I'd like to search them.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What Operating System?

Comment: ditto. Though from what i can tell, there's no working way to mount a 7z archive in filesystem in linux, which would allow him to use the usual *nix file tools to search.

Comment: @Martin: search for which criteria? name? bytes inside the files stored in the .7z?

Comment: OS: Windows; Criteria example: "my string"

Comment: There are a few utilities that do this very well. See newest answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On Windows, use a command prompt:

```
cd C:\Program Files\7-Zip
7z
```

To search for a specific file, e.g. `namefile`:

```
7z l compressed.tar namefile -r
```

Video tutorial: *[Search files with 7-Zip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnIDopVXChY)*

Comment: Yes, this works, and it is quite fast, especially if there is not a lot of matches. But the folder where 7z.exe lives must be in PATH, for example `C:\Program Files\7-Zip`. However, it does ***not*** search the ***content*** of files, only the file names and thus does not answer the question.

Comment: Damn fast, really good. It's a pitty that this function is not available in the gui.

Comment: I second @PeterMortensen's comment: this does not answer the question, it only searches in filenames, not content.

Answer (score 6):

WinRAR can do it. However, let's face that fact it involves unpacking it, even though WinRAR does it seamlessly.

[image: WinRAR, searching an archive]

Comment: This does indeed work. It will find text inside .7z archives and list all the occurrences. When the search is done you can select all the list with CTRL+A. I could not find a way to copy, export or save the results.

Comment: The rar.exe command may be called from CLI with an `i` command to search, similar to above, and `\*.*` for all files. The limitation here, as far as I can make out, is that it will only search *.rar archives. Files with any other extension will produce a `is not a RAR file` response.

Answer (score 5):

[dnGrep](http://dngrep.github.io/) is an excellent Windows grep implementation that has an archive file plugin that works with all archive formats. You can use Regex, Xpath, Text, or phonetic for your search.

Comment: Just installed this. When I try to run it, I see dnGREP.exe in the process list, but no GUI appears. Tried killing it and relaunching it to no effect.  Will have to try something else.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, there exist a few utilities that can search the
contents of files inside compressed archives with no decompression.
Below are a couple of such products:

- [dnGrep](https://dngrep.github.io/)
  Free and open-source, it can search zip, 7z, rar, jar, and many more archive
  formats.
  It also displays a preview of the found text in the files contained inside
  the archive.
  I tested it and it works as claimed.

  [image]
- [MythicSoft](https://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorlite/download/)
  FileLocator Pro and Agent Ransack (commercial)
  Both products advertise their capability for searching compressed archives,
  but I have not tested it.

Answer (score 3):

Try out SearchInZipFiles:
It is a simple Open Source Tool for Windows located on Sourceforge:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/searchinzipfiles/?source=directory

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Linux with 7-Zip installed:

```
find . -iname *7z -exec 7zr -l \{\} \; | grep "filename.cpp"
```

Comment: That is still unpacking them. Although it is not possible to do what the OP wants without unpacking them, so...

Comment: I'm in agreement with EBGreen.  You gotta unpack them, unless you are ok with incomplete results.

Comment: Doesn’t that command just search for *filenames*? Martin wants to search ***inside** the files themselves*, not just their names.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, no there is no way. To examine the **contents** of a file, it needs to be unpacked (regardless of if the files are compressed solid or not or if they are encrypted or not). The only way that you can avoid having to decompress the files is if they are added with the *store* method (ie, not compressed at all, just globbed together).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's not possible with 7z out-of-the-box, without decompressing it to a temporary storage.

I hope there is a nice solution that someone will post to solve this (thus the bounty I started).

However:

- it's possible for .gz files:

  ```
  zgrep "hello" foo.txt.gz
  ```
- it's possible for .xz files:

  ```
  xzgrep "hello" foo.txt.xz
  ```

  See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xzgrep.1.html.

  Note that .xz files use the *same compression algorithm* than .7z, LZMA2, but it only compresses one file and not many files, except if you use tar (but that's out of topic here).

Conclusion: if you want to archive with a good compression ratio (similar to 7z), in a format that is searchable easily from command-line, use .xz instead of .7z.