# How to search for files inside an archive?

Tags: 7-zip

Does [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) have search function for filenames? I see nothing in menus or options.

Comment: This question (https://superuser.com/questions/326737/how-do-i-search-the-content-of-7-zip-archives-7z) is not a duplicate, he is asking about the **content of files** and the questions is not exclusively about 7-Zip.

Comment: If not, then maybe another tool that can read `.7z` archives? I think in Linux you can use `7z l` to list stored paths, then parse its output. But I guess you need Windows solution, don't you?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: I'm asking about the 7-Zip tool, I'm not sure if the tag includes the command line version and if it has extra functionality. I have used 7-Zip for years, but I can of course as alternative measures if 7-Zip lacks search - that's another question.

Comment: @user598527  are you sure the answer to (https://superuser.com/questions/326737/how-do-i-search-the-content-of-7-zip-archives-7z ) doesn't hold good in your case ? From what I know , he tells about filename search in 7z using 7z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows command line version of 7-zip is an executable called 7za.exe.  You can use the "l" switch to list the contents of an archive.

> 7za l C:\path\to\archive.7z

(That's a lower-case L with no slash or dash in front)

To search for a specific file, you can pipe the result through findstr.

> 7za l C:\path\to\archive.7z | findstr "blah"

Comment: `7za.exe` file doesn't exist on my system, 7-Zip version 16.04 installed.

Comment: Do I have to install the "console version"? http://www.7-zip.org/download.html

Comment: I'm not sure about the console version.  Every version I've used has 7za.exe in the installation folder.  It works as a standalone executable, so you could copy it from another system if you prefer.

Comment: I've installed [7-Zip with Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/7zip). I've now downloaded the console version and have started testing.

Comment: How to search for filenames containing? For example, search "history" doesn't find "history.txt" file.

Comment: Worked for me with `7z.exe` instead of `7za.exe` which doesn't exist.